# Uploading a remote file Rails webservice through Carrierwave

Tags: web-services, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am developing a web service in Rails 4 to upload consumer's Image for which I am using carrierwave.

I have configured the carrierwave and tried these commands in console.

```
c=Consumer.first
c.remote_consumer_image_url="http://www.disneyjunior.ca/en/files/392.jpg"
c.save!
```

The above code gives me the expected result but when I had tried the same commands via controller, which gives me the following error.

```
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 126460ms

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Consumer image could not download file: Connection timed out - connect(2)):
```

my controller's code:

```
    @consumer = Consumer.find params[:consumer_id]
    @consumer.remote_consumer_image_url = params[:path]
    @consumer.save!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit obvious, but it looks like a network problem. Your code seems fine.

Have you tried a curl or wget from the same server? Outbound port 80 could be closed. Alternately, have you tried the same code on another machine that you know can access that resource?